# How to Connect external M.2 nvme ssd drive with OTG usb hub

Tags: usb, usb-on-the-go

**Question How to Connect external M.2 nvme ssd drive with OTG usb hub**

I want to take constant nandroid backup of system userdata boot sdext2 external micro card through twrp recovery  or any imaging software and want to store apk data backup and nandroid backup in the  external USB hdd

Some expert suggested me OTG usb hub and connect external hdd...new smartphones have type C power connector and have 15w to 25w powe connector aa old mobiles have different connectors  and  only supports 1.5 w to max chargers.

Aa usb hub amplifies and balance power between multiple connectors

**My queries**

1. Can I connect type c usb  hub to old 3w connectors
2. As external usb hdd or ssd casings don't have any external usb power how much power wattage it need and how much power do usb hub gives
3. I want to purchase new external hdd or ssd I prefer to invest for samsung evo plus 980 nvme M.2 gen4  which give 3.5 Gbps read write speed  now I  can us a external m.2 casing but can I connect that m.2 casing and get enough power wattage to run it...I hope casings may have some not any external power. Any solution help advice opinion trick to connect device. ( I may use that m.2 drive in my new desktop build later.
4. What throughput bandwidth read write speed do OTG  hub gives on devices

Comment: Are you aware that a lot of device having USB-C connector still only supports USB 2.0 speed? Check the device specification which USB mode is supported by your device.

Comment: as you can see on this picture OTG charge hubs have 4x cables: 3x USB connector + 1x charge jack where the external power supply must connected. Phone connected via micro-USB or USB-C (I have both) does not provide enough power for external HDD https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1eEf.jpg

Comment: @alecxs bro thanx didn't saw the charger cable gr8 can  u help tell me the  best or photo u shared  of  OTG usb hub. With usb 3.1 or 3.2 support .. does  samsung galaxy f62 or f42 supports usb 3.0  ....and lastly can we plug use these OTG usb hub in old mobiles with type A socket not type c or any converter

Comment: as Robert stated check phone [specifications](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_f42_5g-11124.php) yourself. Same for old devices check if USB On-The-Go is supported at all

Comment: Type-C OTG Hub is very slow ~0.5 MB/s https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJvDQ.jpg

Comment: @alcexs bro which hub will give  good speed will type a good ans how to interconnect type a  usb hub to type c socket or type c to type a any converter cable which don't diminish speed

Comment: No, there isn't. The limitation probably comes from phone (Poco M3) and there are currently no phones with USB 3.0 out there. Not sure OTG hub has that limitation too. Tried without OTG hub and connected directly 
with 3.1 cable but HDD did not power on :/

Comment: @alecxs bro poco x3 pro (33w charger) have ufs 3.1 to which samsng galaxy s21 series have...there are some pcie nvme Silverstone raven  m.2  casing https://www.silverstonetek.com/product.php?pid=1007&area=en and samsung t5 external hdd which have both type c type a cables and usb 3.1  cables puls thuderbollt 3 which can directly be connected to  android phones without hub must be casing have some external.power...

Comment: @alcecxs bro ufs 2.1 ufs 3.1 and emmc  in which ufs 3.1 gives  good sequential write and read speed  and emmc is slowest but don't know ufs. Is said for. Internal memory rom read write or external micro sd or external usb drive attached or for all

Comment: [Samsung Galaxy S21](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s21-10693.php) has USB Type-C 3.2 it might work with Silverstone Raven (maybe OTG Hub is already integrated inside) [Poco X3 Pro](https://www.gsmarena.com/xiaomi_poco_x3_pro-10802.php) only has USB Type-C 2.0 so most likely as slow as Poco M3

Comment: @alecx bro I am want  economic phone 
with ufs 3.1 + usb 3.1 or 3.2 foundd from gsmarena  text search and filtered  motorala edge S which have both UFS 3.1 usb 3.1 will work with  external silvetone m.2 casing or  samsung galaxy S20 FE is with usb 3.2    is also budgeted but little expensive then motorala but their camera is 12 mp and low battery...what is say about motorala phone are they good https://m.gsmarena.com/compare.php3?idPhone1=10428&idPhone2=10705.  India compare https://www.91mobiles.com/compare/Samsung/Galaxy+S20+FE-35156/vs/Motorola/Edge+S-35622/vs/Samsung/Galaxy+F62-35487.html

Comment: @alecx bro I want to know is usb 3.1 or usb 3.2 is need for Silverstone m.2 casing with smartphone can sumasung x5  external add can connect directly to smartphone

Comment: ask the seller or buy silverstone and do some test before actually buying phones